# Final non-static data member

Tags: java, final, non-static

If you are not allowed to initialize a `final` non-`static` data member twice, then how can I set `x` to something that I want in the following example?

```
class Temp6
{
    final int x;

    Temp6()
    {
        System.out.println(this.x);
        this.x=10;
    }

    public static void main(String[]s)
    {
        Temp6 t1 = new Temp6();
        System.out.println(t1.x);
    }
}
```

Java by default gives `x` a value of `0`, so how can I change it to `10`?.

Answer (score 0):

A variable marked `final` in Java can only be initialized once.

Simply declaring `x` with `final int x;` does not initialize it. Therefore, it is legal to assign to `x` in the `Temp6` constructor. However, you would not be able to assign a different value to `x` after the constructor.

That is, the assignment to `t1.x` in the following:

```
public static void main(String[] s) {
  Temp6 t1 = new Temp6();
  t1.x = 11; // ERROR
}
```

is not legal.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize final variables in the class constructor.

```
public class Blam
{
    private final int qbert;

    public Blam(int qbertValue)
    {
        qbert = qbertValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading `this.x` in your code should give an error, because `final` variables are not initialized upon declaration. `t1.x` should be `10` because `x` is definitely assigned at the end of the sole constructor.

**You have to swap the two lines in the constructor for it to compile and it will be 10 there.**

```
class Temp {
    int x; // declaration and definition; defaulted to 0
    final int y; // declaration, not initialized
    Temp() {
         System.out.println(x); // prints 0
         x = 1;
         System.out.println(x); // prints 1
         x = 2; // last value, instance.x will give 2

         System.out.println(y); // should be a compiler error: The blank final field y may not have been initialized
         y = 3; // definite assignment, last and only value, instance.y will be 3 whereever used
         System.out.println(y); // prints 3
         y = 4; // compile error: The final field y may already have been assigned
    }
}
```

I never thought about this before, interesting point here.
[Final field variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.2) behave like [local variables in methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4.2), they must be [explicitly assigned](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-16.html#jls-16.2) before usage (definite assignment is hard to formalize, see JLS reference, but it's quite logical).

If you want to give a value to `x` from outside, you could do it like this:

```
public class Temp {
    private final int x;
    public Temp(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public int getX() { return this.x; }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Temp temp = new Temp(10);
        System.out.println(temp.getX()); // 10
    }
}
```

Comment: @user139256 wow, that's wicked, it allows for some bugs then; anyway swap your println and assignment, and you'll get 10 twice in your code.

Answer (score -1):

`final` variable are java constants. They should be initialized before class loads.

```
final int x=10;
```

If your final variable is static then it's not like you have to give the value at the declaration itself, you can have something like -

```
class Demo {
  static final int x;

   static {
        x = 10;
   }
}
```

static block gets executed only once, at the time of class loading

Comment: `static` has nothing to do with `final` instance variables (fields); a constant you're talking about is `static final Type name = value;`

Comment: Just explaining that you have to give value before class loads that can also be done with static block not only direct initialization.

Comment: That's true, but your code doesn't compile, `x` is instance and `static {}` is static, static scope can't access instance variables without an explicit instance. There are instance initializer blocks, see [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) and [specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.6)

Comment: Oops.. That was a typo. In description I have mentioned about static though. Changed the code